# ActiveDirectory/C++: How to translate Guid to User Name?

Tags: c++, windows, active-directory

Question in the title. I have the Guid of a user, and want to get the user name from Active Directory. I have been googling and looking at [an example from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/example-code-for-searching-for-users), but can't get it working. And every google hit I get is showing how to do it in C#, while I need it in C++. Any ideas? Preferably I'd like to just get the user name from AD, but any suggestions to get the example working is also appreciated.

External symbols `IID_IDirectorySearch` and `IID_IADs` not found in any of the dll's I'm linking to.

UPDATE:
Thanks to Gabriels answer, I am now able to get the given name. But I still can't find the UserPrincipalName//logonName/sAMAccountName.

```
// Using this code to get the user object:
hr = ADsGetObject(L"LDAP://<GUID=XXXXXXXX-XX...>",
                  IID_IADsUser,
                  (void**)&pADsUser);
// Then trying different ways of getting the logon name:
pADsUser->Get(BSTR("sAMAccountName"), &var);
pADsUser->get_Name(&sbstr);
```

What am I missing?

UPDATE2. Here is my code.

```
IADsUser* pADsUser = NULL;
BSTR sbstr;

HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
if (hr != S_OK) { return; }

hr = ADsGetObject(L"LDAP://<GUID=XXX-YYY>",
    IID_IADsUser,
    (void**)&pADsUser);

if (hr != S_OK) { return; }

// This works
if (S_OK == pADsUser->get_FullName(&sbstr)) {
    printf("Full Name: %S\n", sbstr);
}

// This doesn't. Get returns 0x8000500d
VARIANT var;
VariantInit(&var);
hr = pADsUser->Get(BSTR("sAMAccountName"), &var);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    printf("FullName: %S\n", V_BSTR(&var));
    VariantClear(&var);
}
pADsUser->Release();
CoUninitialize();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That link you included is about performing a search. But if you have the GUID, you don't need to search. You can bind directly to the object using the GUID using an LDAP path in this format:

```
LDAP://servername/<GUID=XXXXX>
```

You can exclude the `servername` if the computer you are running this on is joined to the same or trusted domain as the account you're looking for.

More details here: [Using objectGUID to Bind to an Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/using-objectguid-to-bind-to-an-object)

After binding, then you read the `sAMAccountName` to get the username.

As for the linking, you need to include `activeds.h` and link to `ActiveDS.lib` and `ADSIid.lib` (both are found in the Windows SDK). More details here (this is an old article, but still relevant): [Setting Up Visual C++ 6.0 for ADSI Development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/setting-up-c---for-adsi-development)

There is sample code in [the documentation for `IADs::Get`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nf-iads-iads-get), which shows you how to get both single-value and multi-value attributes. Something like this should work for `sAMAccountName`:

```
VARIANT var;
VariantInit(&var);

hr = pUsr->Get(CComBSTR("sAMAccountName"), &var );
if ( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
{
    printf("User name: %S\n", V_BSTR(&var) );
    VariantClear(&var);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm a total n00b in AD. I am now able to get the given name, but can't find the sAMAccountName anywhere (I've looked in Iads.h). Added some code in the original question. What am I missing?

Comment: I updated my answer. I looked up some code I used before. It's pretty close to what's in the documentation. It's also close to what you're already doing.

Comment: That's exactly the code I'm using, but it fails to get the "sAMAccountName"...

Comment: What do you mean by "fails"?

Comment: SUCCEEDED(hr) returns false. hr = 0x8000500d

Comment: I just tested this out myself. I do get the same error code with your code, but if I use `CComBSTR("sAMAccountName")` like the documentation shows, then it works. You need to include `atlbase.h` to use [`CComBSTR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ccombstr-class).

Comment: Fabulous! It works like a charm :) Thank you so much for your kind help.